# Using Websocket Subscribe call multiple times?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, angular6, subscribe

My Web-socket-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';



export class Headers {
  public name = 'Authorization';
  public value = 'Bearer ';
}


export class Request {
  public id: string;
  public method = 'GET';
  public path = 'EmployeeList/';
  public dataFormat = 'application/json';
  public headers: Headers;
  public data: Data;
  constructor(
    id,
    method,
    path,
    dataFormat,
    headers
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.method = method;
    this.path = path;
    this.dataFormat = dataFormat;
    this.headers = headers;
  }

}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  public serverMessages = new Array<Request>();
  public id = 12;
  public method = 'GET';
  public path = 'EmployeeList/';
  public dataFormat = 'application/json';
  public headers: Headers;
  public headersArray: Headers[]


  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<Request>;

  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
    this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject('url');
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headersArray =[];

    this.headers.value = this.headers.value.concat(this.oidcSecurityService.getToken());
    this.headersArray.push(this.headers);
    this.headersArray.push({name : 'request_id',value : Math.round (Date.now()/1000).toString()})

  }

  GetData() {
    debugger;
    this.path = 'EmployeeList/';
    const message = new Request(this.id, 'GET', this.path, this.dataFormat,  this.headersArray);
    console.log(message);
    message.data = null;
   this.socket$.next(message);
    return this.socket$;
  }

  InsertData(newData) {
    const message = new Request('', 'POST', this.path, this.dataFormat, this.headers);
    message.data = newData;
    this.socket$.next(message);
    return this.socket$;
  }
  UpdateData(SimData) {
    const message = new Request('', 'PUT', this.path, this.dataFormat, this.headers);
    message.data = SimData;
    this.socket$.next(message);
    return this.socket$;
  }
  DeleteDatabyID(Id) {
    this.path = `${'EmployeeList'}/${Id}`;
    const message = new Request(Id, 'Delete', this.path, '', this.headers);
    message.data = null;
    this.socket$.next(message);
    return this.socket$;
  }


  GetEmployeeReportData() {
    this.path = 'EmployeeReports/';
    const message = new Request(this.id, 'GET', this.path, this.dataFormat, this.headers);
    message.data = null;
    this.socket$.next(message);
    return this.socket$;
     }
    }
```

my employeeListComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";

import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormArray,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";
import { OidcSecurityService } from "angular-auth-oidc-client";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
import { WebSocketService } from "./../../core/services/web-socket.service";
import { Data } from "./../../core/services/web-socket.service";
import { DeleteComponent } from "./../delete/delete.component";



@Component({
  selector: "app-simulator",
  templateUrl: "./employeeList.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./employeeList.component.scss"]
})

export class employeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  emplist;

  constructor(
    private socketService: WebSocketService,
    private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef,
    public dialog: MatDialog,

  ) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.GetemployeeList();

  }

  GetemployeeList() {
    this.socketService.GetData().subscribe(
      response => {
       this.emplist= response;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
  }


  InsertEmployee() {
    let data = new Data();
    // data.name = "abc"
       ......

    this.socketService.InsertData(data).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.snackBar.open("employee Added Successfully!", "Success", {
          duration: 2000,
          verticalPosition: "top"
        });
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    this.aviatorForm.reset();
    data = null;
  }

  UploadEmployee(empdata,id) {
    let data = new Data();
   // data.name = empdata.name
     .....
    this.socketService.UpdateData(data).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackBar.open("Simulator Updated Successfully!", "Success", {
        duration: 2000,
        verticalPosition: "top"
      });
    });
  }


  }

}
```

my employeeReportsComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { WebSocketService } from './../../core/services/web-socket.service';
import { Reports } from './Reports';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reports',
  templateUrl: './employeeReports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employeeReports.component.scss']
})
export class employeeReportsComponent implements OnInit {
  Reports;

  constructor(private socketService: WebSocketService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.GetReports();
  }

  GetReports() {
    this.socketService.GetEmployeeReportData().subscribe((response) => {
      this.Reports = response;

      console.log(this.Reports);
    },
      (error) => (console.log(error))
    );
    this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
  }


}
```

I am following [this](https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-websocket-node-31f421c753ff) article

**Question**

When I user multiple subscribed in components then method call multiple times?

example: when i use three subscribed then method call three times.
Am i doing wrong?

Is the structure i followed right or not? i am new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use .pipe(share()) to share the observable between your listeners.

https://blog.strongbrew.io/how-share()-can-reduce-network-requests/

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html

Comment: thanks for your replay. but i used WebsocketSubject.. I usedsocket$.next(message) for call database api. i have two components both have subscribed method. so how can i implement please help?

Answer (score 0):

based on the [rxjs doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket) it is vary good it will not create a new instance on every request, only if you will call `new wocketSubject('url')` on every of your WebSocketService Methods then it will create a new instance for every call, `WebSocketSubject` is returning Subject with something that is called in RXJS a **Hot Observable** that meens it will start on the first subscribe and from then on all new subscriptions get the data from that point on.

PS in chrome dev tools in the Network section you can see if it will create a new instance or not, if u created a new instance it will create a new record, if you didn't create a new instance you will see the new messages on the original record.